# Кракозябры при чтении исключения, выводящего русский текст ошибки Windows

Tags: python, строки, python-2.x

Python 2.7 (**обязательно**)

```
import os
try:
    os.remove('C:/swapfile.sys')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Выводит в UTF-консоли:

```
[Error 32] ������� �� ����� �������� ������ � �����,: 'C:/swapfile.sys'
```

а надо:

```
[Error 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:/swapfile.sys'
```

Comment: Вы кодировку в скрипте указали?

Comment: Это весь код скрипта !!

Comment: А если в начале скрипта добавить: `# coding=<encoding name>`?

Почитать можно тут: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#defining-the-encoding

Comment: а зачем мне добавлять , если у меня в скрипте (в коде) нет русского текста?

Comment: @Eleferen, ему научиться надо понятию `locale`.